# Try to move users from selection in CSV Error "Move-CsUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value..."

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have created a Power Shell script for using in S4B... but I have got
stuck with a problem, maybe someone can help me pass trough that
issue.

The error message that I get is following:

```
Move-CsUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value   {SamAccountName=Account01B}" to type
"Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.UserIdParameter". Error: "Cannot convert
the "@{SamAccountName=ACCOUNT01B}" value of type "Se
lected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type
"Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.UserIdParameter"." At line:25 char:27
+     Move-CsUser -Identity $Fullname -Target pool101.test.se -Confirm:false
+                           ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-CsUser],  ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : nnotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.Cmdlets.MoveOcsUserCmdlet
```

Not only that, it look like FOREACH not looping aswell...

The Script look like this:

```
# Exporting out Data to CSV file
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss')
Get-CsUser | Where-Object {$_.RegistrarPool -match "Pool101.test.se" -and
$_.ConferencingPolicy -notmatch "AllowInMeetings"} | Select-Object
SamAccountName | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp
\Change_Call_Policy_access_Users_$CurrentDate.csv" -NoTypeInformation

#Variables
File = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Change_Call_Policy_access_Users_$CurrentDate.csv"
Log = New-Item -ItemType File -Path "C:\Temp\changed_users_log.txt" -Force

#Import csv
usercsv = Import-Csv -path $file -Delimiter ','
Check if user file is empty.
if ($Usercsv -eq $null)
{
    Add-Content $Log -Value "$($CurrentDate) No Users Found in the Input File      
    change_Call_Policy_access_Users_$CurrentDate.csv"
    exit 0
}
```

Check after SamAccountName that ends on `'[n-z5-9]$'` in UserCSV

```
ForEach ($user in $usercsv) 
{
    $Fullname = $usercsv | Where-Object {$_.SamAccountName -match '[n-z5-9]$'} |  
    Select-Object SamAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    Move-CsUser -Identity $Fullname -Target pool02.test.se -Confirm:false
    Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "$($FullName) not enabled.  $(Get-
    Date)$($error[0])"

    Write-Host "Change users from CSV completed!"
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host ""
}
Move-Item -Path $File -Destination C:\Temp\Archive
update-csuserdatabase -verbose
sleep -seconds 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this, it was missing a $...

//Nils